# Is there a way to filter for more than one value in the same column of a table?

Tags: python, django, database

I am building a Website, where you can filter for beverages with many parameters, for example for the name of an Item, for the brand usw... But I also want to add a checkbox field, where you can mark certain volumes and filter my database for them.

So lets say, I want to filter by the name Cola, by brand Coca Cola and by Volume 0.7L and 1L. Now I want that all Items in my table get displayed, which have the name Cola brand Coca Cola and which have a volume of 0.7 liter and 1 liter

This does not work, because I filter for two different values in one column, which is not possible in this way, because the field "volume" can't be 0.7 and 1.

```
qsf = Content.objects.all().filter(Q(products__icontains=Cola) & Q(volume=0.7) & Q(volume=1) & Q(brand=Coca Cola))
```

I can't use the or operator (|) either, because then my filter doesn't work.

This is like my 3 post, because I don't know how to solve this problem, I really hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `|` operator, you probably just need to use parenthesis to group the Q objects

```
qsf = Content.objects.all().filter(
    Q(products__icontains='Cola') &
    (Q(volume=0.7) | Q(volume=1)) &
    Q(brand='Coca Cola')
)
```

Comment: I used parenthesis, I just forgot them here. But it still don't work then because if I don't type in a name and just search for the volume, I get displayed all items in my database. It also don`t work when the first volume is none (because the checkbox with 0.7 is not checked) than there is just an empty string and I get displayed all Items again. I am very sorry, but I am not able to explain my problem better :/. I just can say it don't work with the | operator.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from missing parens, I can't see what's wrong with your post, but maybe the following is better/ easier to follow.

Use multiple `filter`. In general, filter using `Q`  and `|` for or-type selection within a column, multiple `.filter` for and-type selection on a different column for each filter. (You can of course and-combine multiple filter clauses in one `.filter` operation, and in this case I think you could also use `.filter( volume__in = [0.7, 1.0] )` ).

Maybe try

```
 qsf = Content.objects.all(
      ).filter( products__icontains='Cola'
      ).filter( 
          Q(volume=0.7) | Q(volume=1) 
      ).filter( brand='Coca Cola'
  )
```

(I'm not entirely happy with this code formatting. Maybe better to close the `.filter` and use backslash to continue on the next line? Anyway, not relevant)